# Topological configurations and phase transitions

Tags: phase-transition, topology, topological-field-theory

It is known that topological defects might appear only during phase transitions of the first kind, while continuous transitions of the second kind and crossovers don't product them. How to explain that?

Comment: Not sure where you got that wild claim. KT transition is driven by proliferation of topological defects, and it is a continuous transition.

Comment: @MengCheng : maybe my question have to be rephrased by the next way: why Kibble mechanism of formation of topological defects during phase transitions isn't relevant for the second order transition for cosmology?

Comment: @MengCheng : may I ask you about KT transition?